# Getting Request Parameter Value Writes the Result into the Source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery, but I've been able to get around and it's been fun. I came across something at work, however, that is boggling my mind. And it's not something I really know how to explain either, so I attached a screenshot.

I have this function (there are a few variables that I have access to such as $formItem, $request, $object, $jQuery, $widgetId, $ajaxUrl, and params, that are given to me):

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeRandomName" id="SomeRandomId" value="Hello"/>

function reload(element) {
    var result = $request.getParameter("SomeRandomId");
    console.log("Result");
    console.log(result);
}
```

When I load the page, I get this issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROIJX.png

It seems the value is being written directly into the code? If I try to wrap the result in strings or append it, I get an error saying it's not possible. What can I do in this situation?

Let me know if you need anything else. This is the first time I've encountered this problem.

I've tried using jQuery, but the data disappears when the form is submitted and that is an issue at work. We need the data to persist when the form is submitted and bounced back. The process we do that in is by calling $request and assigning a velocity variable the data. I could not do this procedure in this case because I am dynamically re-assigning HTML elements their original value.

Comment: When you are assigning result to 'Hello' in console it should be in single quotes as it's a string. Should be let result = 'Hello'. Although I am not quite sure about the actual issue here.

Comment: Oh my gosh, it worked! I spent so long trying to get it working. I noticed appending it to a string doesn't work. It has to be wrapped inside single quotes? I noticed double quotes don't work. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Can you accept the answer then :)

Comment: Yes! It will let me accept it in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning result to 'Hello' in console it should be in single quotes as it's a string. Should be let result = 'Hello'.

Comment: One more thing ... I tried '$request.getParameter("${element.id}_data")'; and it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to insert the element.id (HTML element). But if I print element.id, it works. What am I doing wrong here?